# ssl certificate Not secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have a domain registered at ionos.com "somedomain.site" they give me a wildcard certificate *.somedomain.site, which I installed on aws ec2 tomcat successfully.

if i access https://ec2-xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/ the padlock shows Not secure, but display page contents.

if redirect/forward (iframe) from ionos to aws then access http://somedomain.site it 
displays "Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue"

accessing https://somedomain.site displays "Secure Connection Failed"

how to fix this so the padlock shows secure. thanks.

Comment: In order for the SSL certificate to work it should match the certificate domain to the domain that the certificate is installed, having said that somedomain.site ssl will not work in your https://ec2-xxxx.us-east-2. But it should work in your https://somedomain.site IF it's correctly installed. In case the EC2 is under ELB you should have a rule in your ELB to accept secure requests. In order for the ELB to use your SSL cert, you need to import it using AWS certificate manager.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL must match the domain that you are currently using. If you have a wildcard make sure I'd assume it includes the APEX domain too.

It's worth checking out https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ on your domain, it will tell you exactly whats wrong.